# How do I create the UI of the Stocks application on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, stocks

I'm not interested in getting the stock data, but I want to create a smilar application that will have the exact same UI as Apple's Stocks application on the iPhone.

Does anybody know of a tutorial or open code repo that can show me how to do this?

Comment: You'd probably get some downvotes for this question. You should google and I'm sure you'll find many resources. Also for the UI, you must do it with code and some image files, so that's not understandable what you're looking for.

Also check out Apple sample codes. You'll find helpful stuff there.

Comment: That would be a copyright violation, if you do it exactly the same.

Comment: There was a WWDC video (from 2012 or 2011) that introduced Core Graphics by drawing something similar to the Stocks app (or at least the chart part of the app).

Answer (score 1):

There will be no such tutorial, because the stocks app use a huge number of different technics, and graphical effects.

If you read the ViewController Programming Guide, and then CoreGraphics (Quartz) Guide, then you are near to do it yourself.

Ask again if you have a more specific question.